# Git add in a specific directory show modification file but the output site doesn't change

Tags: git, docker-compose

I have a private remote repository and update a file inside the local branch, adding this `console.log('test')`

Then add it

```
 git add .
```

When I check

```
git status -s
```

I see

```
M  path/toFile.js
```

but why when I am running the site locally, I can't see my `console.log`.

what a strange, when i updated file in a different directory, it can change and show the result, what's wrong with this? i using git and docker-compose up to build this locally

when i running the browser in incognito mode, it showing normally, i can see my `console.log` here, what a strange

Comment: If you're just running things locally, you shouldn't need to commit them to see the changes. What exactly are you running?

Comment: It should work. How you run the site? Something automated ?

Comment: yes i running docker-compose up, try docker-compose down, still not change

Comment: Can you show you docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a remote repo that is shared by multiple people.  Someone has made a change to that remote repo and you want to run/test the files locally.

To get someone else's changes to your system, they will need to post their changes to the remote server and then you will need to pull them down.

To be able to test out changes across multiple people without "checking" them in is not how your usage of git is setup.

Most likely, you want your team members to start a new branch, make their changes to that branch locally, commit and push that brunch up to the server, then you pull down that branch and test it out.  If everything work as intended, then you merge that branch into your master branch and then push that updated code up to the server.

Comment: i pull that from remote branch, and make a update, then i test it, not yet done the job, but i cant test the output, still in develop progress